# Simple Continued Fraction of the Natural Numbers

Tags: bessel-functions, continued-fractions

According to [the OEIS wiki](https://oeis.org/wiki/Continued_fractions) the continued fraction $[0, 1, 2, 3, 4...]$ is equal to $\frac{I_1(2)}{I_0(2)} \approx 0.697774657964...$, where $I_n$ is the Modified Bessel Function of the First Type.

This is rather surprising to me, I can't think of a good reason why Bessel Functions ought to be involved.  Why is this the case?

Comment: Short answer: due to the cosine addition formulas, Bessel functions fulfill the right recurrence relation to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!